# Radius of convergence in terms of distance

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $G$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$ and $0\in G$ and $f:G\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be analytic. If $f$ is analytic at $0$ and has a power series expansion at $0$, is it possible to conclude that the radius of convergence of the power series around $0$ is $dist(0,\delta G)$, where $\delta G$ is the boundary of G?

Comment: The radius of convergence is *at least* ${\rm dist}(0,\partial G)$, but it would not be correct to say it's exactly this. It might be possible to take some analytic continuation of $f$. For example, any polynomial $p(z)$ is certainly analytic on the open unit disk, but it's power series converges on all of $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @Glare Thanks for the reply. Shall you give me a hint or a source, so that I can carry out the proof myself?